# IOS - Calculating tiles to display in a MapRect when

Tags: iphone

I have tried the solution on this but get 2 errors when I run the build. First "MAX_ZOOM undeclared" and Implicit declaraation of function'zoomScaleToZoomLevel'

I'm new to xCode, any help? need to fix tile zooming.
Thanks Ken

[Calculating tiles to display in a MapRect when "over-zoomed" beyond the overlay tile set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417545/calculating-tiles-to-display-in-a-maprect-when-over-zoomed-beyond-the-overlay-t)

Answer (score 0):

MAX_ZOOM is a constant - you need to define it someplace in your code to match the number of zoom levels in your tile set.