# How to zoom in on map tiles instead of drawing next zoom level

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, openstreetmap

I've been using [this code](https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo) to display `OpenCycleMap` tiles on my app's `mapview`, but if I zoom in too far the map tiles will disappear. Since `OCM` tiles may not exist at close zoom levels (say, 15 or 16 for a certain area), they just don't appear when drawing the maps for a certain zoom level, and the mapview only shows the Google Street map that is underneath the `OCM` overlay.

Is there a way to edit the code to make the mapview display whichever map tiles are available for an area, but resized for the region that the mapview shows?

Comment: hey guthook, from the PCT I assume. Your question is asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417545/calculating-tiles-to-display-in-a-maprect-when-over-zoomed-beyond-the-overlay

Comment: Hmm... thanks Craig. Doesn't seem to have the answer for the code I'm using (I have the same problem the more recent commenter in that question has, using the mtigas code), but this is much closer than anything I've found so far. I'll have to play around with this a bit.